# DeviceNetworkInformation.IsCellularDataEnabled always returns false

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-emulator

I recently installed the Windows Phone 8.1 emulators to try some existing apps out on them and ran into this problem: `DeviceNetworkInformation.IsCellularDataEnabled` (in the `Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation` namespace) is always returning false.

```
public void UpdateDataEnabled()
{
    _dataEnabled = DeviceNetworkInformation.IsCellularDataEnabled 
        || DeviceNetworkInformation.IsWiFiEnabled;
}
```

[image: DeviceNetworkInformation.IsCellularDataEnabled = false]

I know the connection is actually working because I'm still able to perform HTTP requests. If I run this same exact code in the 8.0.x emulators I don't have any problems.

I also tried updating the project and all libraries to Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 apps to see if that would resolve the issue and no luck. I checked all the capabilities and ID_CAP_NETWORKING was still checked as well.

The emulator is tested and working if I write a pure Windows Phone 8.1 XAML app using [Windows 8 method of obtaining network status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402563%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_networking). It's just not working for my Silverlight apps.

I was under the impression that Windows Phone Silverlight apps should continue to function on Windows Phone 8.1 devices. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Did you enable the “fake GSM” in the simulator options? It’s disabled by default.

Comment: Yes, fake GSM is enabled as well. Tested and working if I write a pure Windows Phone 8.1 XAML app using [Windows 8 method of obtaining network status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402563%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_networking). It's just not working for my Silverlight app.

Comment: Sorry then, I'll let specialists respond at this point :)

Comment: Thanks for the idea! It's probably something simple like this that I am overlooking. :)

Comment: Yep same thing spend a day on f*** Ling Query and it was just… not a good order for variables… I hope for you it’s something like this and you find people here to point it out!!! I would love to help (I’m working on 8.1 app myself) but I think my knowledge has limits lol

Comment: I think it's only an emulator issue

Comment: Why dont you use IsNetworkAvailable instead of checking both wife and mobile date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem and i did what verdesrobert and Rishabh876 suggested. Its only emulator problem so i add condition to check out if app is running on emulator

```
    public bool IsNetworkAvailable()
    {
        if (DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable)
        {
            if (Microsoft.Devices.Environment.DeviceType == DeviceType.Emulator)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if ((DeviceNetworkInformation.IsWiFiEnabled || DeviceNetworkInformation.IsCellularDataEnabled) && NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.None)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I dont like that workaround much so if anyone has better solution let me know.

Comment: This seems to be just an emulator bug as it runs fine on my phone. Adding the code you suggested seems to have fixed the issue. I might add preprocessor directive for debugging so this only runs while on the emulator until they fix the issue.

Comment: I did not have this issue when testing on wp8.1 device but once launched to the store the information was not calling properly. I did not have ID_CAP_NETWORKING capability checked when testing and it was woring, is this WP Store requirement?

Comment: i believe that you have to set capability to make it work. and for now i dont develop WP apps any more so i am not sure if this issue is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the WP8.1 emulator is giving that information only to WP8.1 apps.
I'm pretty sure that the 7.1 apps will work properly on WP8.1 Devices.

Comment: You are right, this only seems to be an emulator issue. It runs fine on an actual device.